# Avoid ajax file upload attack

Tags: spring-mvc, file-upload, struts2

I have a form and in a `HTML form` inside which I have file upload button.
File is going to be uploaded using `AJAX` request.

- On file upload I am checking extension and file size.
- I am uploading file into `/home/xyz/upload/username/username_timestamp`

But since I am using AJAX request, I cannot(and don't want to) use the `CAPTCHA` and there is a risk of attacker flooding with files. How can I deal with this issue?

PS: I am using Spring-MVC(not spring security) and Struts2 in my projects, so framework specific solution will be icing on a cake.

Comment: Pretty sure you can still validate a capthica in an ajax request. But also this question is too opinion based and does not meet the MVCE requirements for SO: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: In that case I will have to update CAPTCHA after every file upload request, BTW I don't want to use captcha.

Comment: @Wobbles I know People here need some snippet, but I don't think we need that here, I have kept question precise and explained implementation part thoroughly.

Comment: The question you ask is still too opinion based, its not a good match for SO as questions here are expected to be more of a specific nature and not "how do I ...". But regardless if you dont want to use capthica for human verification what else do you expect to be? You could make a cooldown timer and tie it to sessions and or IP.

Comment: @Wobbles Again Question is not regarding CAPTCHA, Please read the question properly, I want to avoid File upload attack.

Comment: Please read the response properly.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133468/discussion-between-piechuckerr-and-wobbles).

Answer (score 0):

Protect your action to be called out of expected by using [Strut's token mechanism](https://struts.apache.org/docs/token-session-interceptor.html) and your expected logic of file uploads inside your parent action (e.g. max uploads per minutes) ; something like below:

index.jsp

```
<form action="upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
      <label for="myFile">Upload your file</label>
      <input type="file" name="myFile" />
      <s:if test="uploadsPerMinutes < 10">
      <s:token name="tknUpload" /> <!-- *** conditional generate token *** -->
      </s:if>
      <sj:submit value="Submit Form" targets="myAjaxTarget"/>
   </form>
<div id="myAjaxTarget">
    </div>
```

struts.xml

```
   <action name="upload" class="com.upload.FileUpload">
      <interceptor-ref name="tokenSession/>
      <interceptor-ref name="basicStack"/>
      <result name="success" type="stream">...</result>
   </action>
   <action name="uploadParent" class="com.upload.FileUploadParent">
      <result name="success">index.jsp</result>
   </action>
```

FileUploadParent.java

```
public class FileUploadParent extends ActionSupport{
   ...
   public static int uploadsPerMinutes = 0;
   private static DateTime lastUploadTime;

   public String execute()
   {
      ...
   synchronized(uploadsPerMinutes){
      if(currentTime - lastUploadTime > 1min) uploadsPerMinutes=0;
      else uploadsPerMinutes++;
      lastUploadTime = currentTime;
   }
      return SUCCESS;
   }
   public String getUploadsPerMinutes()
   {
      return uploadsPerMinutes;
   }
}
```

With these, client have to get a token from server for each file upload. These are behind the scene and do not disturb your normal users.

Comment: but token will be get coupled with JSP Form when page gets reloaded,  tokenizing will not solve this issue.